# Trigger on click of submit button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to trigger a short script click of the following submit button. It should add the "loading" css when the purchase button is clicked. The code will be loaded using Googletagmanager only on this page. The code I am currently attempting is:

```
<script>
 jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
$( '.form-row.place-order' ).click( function() {
$( this ).addClass( 'loading' );
});
});</script>
```

Here is the html

```
<div class="form-row place-order">
<input type="submit" class="button alt" 
name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Finalizar 
compra" data-value="Finalizar compra">
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="6df1de1da5"><input 
type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/?wc-ajax=update_order_review">    
</div>
```

I've also tried it with #place_order instead of .form-row.place-order however in both cases without sucess. Does anybody have an idea what I can?
Thanks for your help.
Best regards,

Comment: `$( '#place-order' ).click( function(event) {
event.preventDefault(); //stop default postback behaviour
$( this ).addClass( 'loading' );
});` . Of course, whether you really want to add this "loading" CSS to the button is open to question...did you mean to add a whole new element to display the "loading" indicator? Also do you then want to submit the form as well? In that case `$(this).closest("form").submit();` as well

Comment: you're not selecting the button input, but the wrapper div, try with `$( '.form-row.place-order .button' )` or simply `$( '#place_order' )` (and might need to adapt inside the function if you want the class to be added to the wrapper div and not the button)

Comment: Your javascript code seem to run when you replace with console.log. Are you sure css class is not added ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine check it out. I think you should check your css class is doing what you mean to do.

```css
.loading input{
  color : white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
$( '.form-row.place-order' ).click( function() {
$( this ).addClass( 'loading' );
});
});</script>
<div class="form-row place-order">
<input type="submit" class="button alt" 
name="woocommerce_checkout_place_order" id="place_order" value="Finalizar 
compra" data-value="Finalizar compra">
<input type="hidden" id="_wpnonce" name="_wpnonce" value="6df1de1da5"><input 
type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/?wc-ajax=update_order_review">    
</div>
```

Comment: it is true it is targeting the wrapper not the actual button though lol

Comment: Div gets its size from the button anyways, so click event fires in both cases :)

Answer (score -2):

I think you should wait for DOM, and just use normal javascript like below
Or maybe your submit is too fast and does not show the animation?

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

    $('#place_order').click(function(e) {
       $(this).addClass('loading');
    });

})();
</script>
```

Comment: This is functionally equivalent to `jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {`. Just syntactic sugar.

Comment: It's the same thing, just less typing :), but updated so it's clearer